# Querying struct within array - Databricks SQL

Tags: sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I am using Databricks SQL to query a dataset that has a column formatted as an array, and each item in the array is a struct with 3 named fields.

I have the following table:

| id | array |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","age":"10"},{"firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Smith","age":"12"}] |
| 2 | [{"firstName":"Bob","lastName":"Miller","age":"13"},{"firstName":"Betty","lastName":"Miller","age":"11"}] |

In a different SQL editor, I was able to achieve this by doing the following:

```sql
SELECT
id,
struct.firstName
FROM
table
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(array) as t(struct)
```

With a resulting table of:

| id | firstName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 1 | Jane |
| 2 | Bob |
| 2 | Betty |

Unfortunately, this syntax does not work in the Databricks SQL editor, and I get the following error.

```sql
[UNRESOLVED_COLUMN] A column or function parameter with name `array` cannot be resolved.
```

I feel like there is an easy way to query this, but my search on Stack Overflow and Google has come up empty so far.

Comment: Hi Philip, could you share a sample of the data you are trying to query and ideally the expected output?

Comment: @BartoszGajda - unfortunately I am unable to share the exact data that I am querying.  But I'll edit my post to attempt to show what I am needing.

Comment: @BartoszGajda - I just edited the post to reflect data that is structured and formatted like mine.  Thanks for the help! (also thanks for the edits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. SQL API

The first solution uses the SQL API. The first code snippet prepares the test case, so you can ignore it if you already have it in place.

```py
import pyspark.sql.types

schema = StructType([
    StructField('id', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("people", ArrayType(StructType([
        StructField('firstName', StringType(), True),
        StructField('lastName', StringType(), True),
        StructField('age', StringType(), True)
    ])), True)
])

sql_df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, [{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","age":"10"},{"firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Smith","age":"12"}]),
    (2, [{"firstName":"Bob","lastName":"Miller","age":"13"},{"firstName":"Betty","lastName":"Miller","age":"11"}])
], schema)
sql_df.createOrReplaceTempView("sql_df")
```

What you need to use is the `LATERAL VIEW` clause ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-lateral-view)) which allows to explode the nested structures, like this:

```sql
SELECT id, exploded.firstName
FROM sql_df
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(sql_df.people) sql_df AS exploded;

+---+---------+
| id|firstName|
+---+---------+
|  1|     John|
|  1|     Jane|
|  2|      Bob|
|  2|    Betty|
+---+---------+
```

#### 2. DataFrame API

The alternative approach is to use `explode` method ([docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html?highlight=explode#pyspark-sql-functions-explode)), which gives you the same results, like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col

sql_df.select("id", explode(col("people.firstName"))).show()

+---+-----+
| id|  col|
+---+-----+
|  1| John|
|  1| Jane|
|  2|  Bob|
|  2|Betty|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: The SQL API solution worked perfectly for me, thank you so much!